# Custom 404 page not working in nextjs 14?

Tags: next.js14

Custom 404 page not working on wrong routes in nextjs 14

After creating a custom 404 page and when try with wrong routes, my custom page is not even rendering, did anyone faced this issue before is it because am amature, is there any solution to find out what wrong am I doing!?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a "not-found.jsx" or "not-found.tsx" file in your app directory so that nextjs renders that file in case the user hits any unsupported route.

You can read about it in depth here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found